# How to go back to a certain point in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to go back to **Main Menu** after every operation is done, like adding students, deleting them etc....I just don't know how to do it, please help.
One more thing, If i create functions for each operation how would it work?

PS: and I'm sorry if someone already posted this question, I couldn't find any question related to this problem, plus I'm new so go easy on me!
**Thanks**

```
import time
import sqlite3
import sys

""" Program Info """
AppName = "Student Manager"
AppVersion = "1.4.2V"
AppAuthor = "Zaidan Chaudhary"

print("{} || {} || {}".format(AppName, AppVersion, AppAuthor))
time.sleep(2)

""" Start Of Program """

print("\n***Welcome To Student Manager***")
print("Main Menu\n\n1: Login\n2: Sign Up\n3: Exit")


"""Start of Program """
def Start():


    """ Creating SQl Database and Table in it """
    con = sqlite3.connect("StudentManager.db")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LoginSystem(firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, username TEXT, password TEXT)")

    """Main Program """

    while True:
        try:
            InputMenu = int(input("Please select an option from Menu: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("\nPlease enter in numbers [1, 2, 3]\n")

    if InputMenu == 1:
        LogUsername = input("Please enter your username: ")
        LogPassword = input("Please enter your password: ")
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM LoginSystem WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", (LogUsername, LogPassword))
        CheckingLogin = cursor.fetchall()


        if CheckingLogin:
            for i in CheckingLogin:
                print("Welcome " + i[0] + "" + i[1] + " to your dashboard\n")

        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Students(firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, grade TEXT, "
                       "age TEXT, phoneNo TEXT, address TEXT)")
    ### This Is My MAIN MENU #####
        print("1: Add Students\n2: View Students\n3: Delete Students\n4: Exit")
        while True:
            try:
                UserEntry = int(input("Please select an option from Main Menu: "))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("\nError!\nPlease enter in numbers...\n")
        if UserEntry == 1:
            StudentFirstName = input("Please enter student's first name: ")
            StudentLastName = input("Please enter student's last name: ")
            StudentGrade = input("Please enter student's grade: ")
            StudentAge = input("Please enter student's age: ")
            StudentPhoneNO = input("Please enter his/her parent's phone number: ")
            StudentAddress = input("Please enter student's home address: ")
            StudentFirstName.title()
            StudentLastName.title()
            StudentGrade.title()
            StudentPhoneNO.title()
            StudentAge.title()
            StudentAddress.title()
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Students VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                           (StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, StudentGrade, StudentAge, StudentPhoneNO,
                            StudentAddress))
            con.commit()
            print("Student Added Successfully!")
        elif UserEntry == 2:
            print("1: View All Students\n2: View By FirstName\n3: View By Grade")
            while True:
                try:
                    Entry = int(input("Please select an option from Menu: "))
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please select in numbers...\n")

            if Entry == 1:
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students")
                AllStudents = cursor.fetchall()
                AllStudents.sort()
                for b in AllStudents:
                    print("Student Name: {} ".format(b[0]) + "{}".format(b[1]))
                    print("Student grade: {}".format(b[2]))
                    print("Student age: {}".format(b[3]))
                    print("Phone Number: {}".format(b[4]))
                    print("Home Address: {}\n".format(b[5]))

            elif Entry == 2:
                ViewFirst = input("Please enter students first name: ")
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE firstName = ?", (ViewFirst,))
                StudentInfo = cursor.fetchall()
                for g in StudentInfo:
                    print("Student Name: {} ".format(g[0]) + "{}".format(g[1]))
                    print("Student grade: {}".format(g[2]))
                    print("Student age: {}".format(g[3]))
                    print("Phone Number: {}".format(g[4]))
                    print("Home Address: {}\n".format(g[5]))

            elif Entry == 3:
                Grade = input("Please enter student's grade/class: ")
                cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE grade = ?", (Grade,))
                StudentGradeInfo = cursor.fetchall()
                for p in StudentGradeInfo:
                    print("Student Name: {} ".format(p[0]) + "{}".format(p[1]))
                    print("Student grade: {}".format(p[2]))
                    print("Student age: {}".format(p[3]))
                    print("Phone Number: {}".format(p[4]))
                    print("Home Address: {}\n".format(p[5]))



        elif UserEntry == 3:
            DelName = input("Enter student's firstname you want to delete: ")
            DelName.title()
            cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Students WHERE firstName = ?", (DelName,))
            con.commit()
            AllStudents = cursor.fetchall()
            print("Student Deleted Successfully")
            for b in AllStudents:
                print(b)

        elif UserEntry == 4:
            print("Closing App......")
            time.sleep(2)
            sys.exit()





        else:
            print("Invalid Username or Password")


    elif InputMenu == 2:
        while True:
            firstName = input("Please enter your First Name: ")
            lastName = input("Please enter your Last Name: ")
            Username = input("Please enter new username: ")
            Password = input("Please enter password: ")
            ConfirmPass = input("Please re-enter password: ")

            if Password == ConfirmPass:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO LoginSystem VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", (firstName, lastName, Username, Password))
                con.commit()
                con.close()
                print("User Registered")

                break

            else:
                print("Error!\n Unable to Register\n Please recheck information")

    elif InputMenu == 3:
        print("Closing App....")
        time.sleep(2)
        sys.exit()

""" End Of Start Function """


Start()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  The given code is hardly minimal.  To go back to a point, simply put a large `while` loop around the stuff you want to repeat.  You already know how to do that.

Comment: Also, don't ask two questions in one. "If i create functions for each operation how would it work?" is a completely separate question from "I want to go back to Main Menu after every operation is done", even if they're about the same code, so they should be asked as separate questions (with separate [mcve]s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this in pseudocode, it will be easier to understand.

```
while True:

    if Operation happening:
        MainMenu.hide()
    elif Operation not happening:
        MainMenu.show()
```

This should work whether the function redirects to a different page or something, because as soon as the function is finished the MainMenu will show (Only when its absolutely sure the operation is not happening, hence the "elif").

To answer your second question, keep a while loop running.

```
running = True

while running:
    command = input('> ')
    if "this_happens":
        execute_function(params)
```

I understand this is the easiest way. Whenever the user wants to do something, they can type it here. Then check what the user wants to do, using if statements, then execute it. You can do it a different way, but this is an example.